# Re-install os x Yosemite beta for developer after mac hd initialized

Tags: macos, formatting, initialization, reinstall, osx-yosemite

I've got os x Yosemite beta 3 for developers.

I need to format or initialise my macintosh HD and re-install it, but how am i sure that i will be able to re-install it? Because if I go on developer.apple.com and I try to re-download the Yosemite from apple store, it tells me that the code is already used; exactly:

```
Code already used
```

So how to know if i will able to re-install the Yosemite beta and not mavericks?

I need Yosemite and i need to format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it from the App Store, using the account you redeemed your code on. From there, you can reinstall it using the app or maybe make a install media using this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856